# jquery ui accordion - render closed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery.ui accordion working. I wish that all the divs are closed on creation.
I always get the first item opened and i can't seem to find in the documentation a way to do it.
Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a combination of the [`active`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active) and [`collapsible`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-collapsible) options:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/gjMfZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

The index value can be boolean or integer

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var activeIndex = parseInt($('#<%=AccordionIndexHidden.ClientID %>').val());
        if (activeIndex < 0) 
            activeIndex = false;
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            event: "mousedown",
            active: activeIndex,
            change: function (event, ui) {
                var index = $(this).children('h3').index(ui.newHeader);
                $('#<%=AccordionIndexHidden.ClientID %>').val(index);
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

Remember to start with index less than 0

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="AccordionIndexHidden" runat="server" Value="-1" />
```